# Why I don't receive event on SignalR with complex object as parameters?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr.client

I have an event in SignalR that doesn't arrive while others that do arrive.

**Sending code:**

```
IHubContext<IServerHubProxy> _hubContext=...
MyClass message1 = new MyClass ();
MyClass message2 = new MyClass () { new MyMessage(Guid.NewGuid(), 0, 1), new MyMessage(Guid.NewGuid(), 1, 1) };
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessage(message1);
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendMessage(message2);
await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendSimpleMessage("Hello");
```

**Receiving code:**

```
IClientHubProxy _hubTypedProxy=...
_hubTypedProxy.SendMessage(args => {
    Console.WriteLine("Messages received: {0} {1}", args.Messages.Count, string.Join(",", args.Messages));
});
_hubTypedProxy.SendSimpleMessage(args => {
    Console.WriteLine("Message received: {0}", args));
});
```

**IServerHubProxy**

```
public interface IServerHubProxy
{
    Task SendMessage(MyClass message);
    Task SendSimpleMessage(string message);
}
```

**IClientHubProxy**

```
public interface IClientHubProxy: IClientHubProxyBase
{
    IDisposable SendMessage(Action<MyClass> messageHandler);
    IDisposable SendSimpleMessage(Action<string> messageHandler);
}
```

**MyClass**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<MyMessage> Messages { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Messages = new List<MyMessage>();
    }
}
```

**MyMessage**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyMessage : MyMessageBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid MessageID { get; set; }

    public MyMessage(Guid messageId, int messageType, int enabled)
        : base(messageType, enabled)
    {
        MessageID = messageId;
    }
}
```

**MyMessageBase**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyMessageBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MessageType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Enabled { get; set; }

    public MyMessageBase(int messageType, int enabled)            
    {
        MessageType = messageType;
        Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Console result:

> Messages received: 0
>   Message received: Hello

Expected result:

> Messages received: 0
>   Messages received: 2 MyMessage,MyMessage
>   Message received: Hello

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some hours of debugging I found out:

- the Receive event was called with the right message (Json format)

so 
I simulated the deserialization process that is done by SignalR, with the message I got from `Received` event, and I finally got

- an exception saying that the type I am trying to convert to needs to have a **parameter-less constructor**.

So the solution to this specific problem would be adding a **parameter-less constructor** to any object you want to use inside the message you want to transmit through SignalR:

**MyMessage**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyMessage : MyMessageBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public Guid MessageID { get; set; }

    public MyMessage(Guid messageId, int messageType, int enabled)
        : base(messageType, enabled)
    {
        MessageID = messageId;
    }

    public MyMessage() { }
}
```

**MyMessageBase**

```
[DataContract]
public class MyMessageBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MessageType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Enabled { get; set; }

    public MyMessageBase(int messageType, int enabled)            
    {
        MessageType = messageType;
        Enabled = enabled;
    }
    public MyMessageBase() { }
}
```